# Mathf.Sign(0) not returning zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why does Mathf.Sign(0) return one in Unity? According to the C# documentation, it should return zero.

```
Mathf.Sign(0.3); // 1
Mathf.Sign(-0.3); // -1
Mathf.Sign(0); // 1, expected 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unity `Mathf.Sign` has it's [own behavior](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sign.html). To get the expected behavior, use the standard C# `Math.Sign` instead.

Comment: or `System.Mathf.Sign` if you don't want to use doubles. Also including the `System` might make it easier to acknowledge that you're using the the C# standard library for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the [`Mathf` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Math/Mathf.cs#L159) you find

> ```
> public static float Sign(float f) { return f >= 0F ? 1F : -1F; }
> ```

as also mentioned in the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sign.html)

> Return value is `1` when `f` is **positive or zero**, `-1` when `f` is negative.

they indeed explicitly skip the `0` value and this always returns `1` or `-1`.

---

As also already mentioned by [Magnesium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68882411/7111561) you should use [`System.Math.Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.math.sign) if you want the `0` behavior.

---

Or actually for using `float` rather than `double` right away you could probably use [`System.MathF.Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.mathf.sign#system-mathf-sign(system-single)) as well